# google map places api -> the region types not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-map-place

**Google map places api not working with regions**

```
    // Define options
    $scope.autocompleteOptions = {
    types: ['regions'],
    componentRestrictions: {country:'aus'}
    };
```

**But api  working with address...**
**i cant understand what i am missing?**

```
 $scope.autocompleteOptions = {
        types: ['address'],
        componentRestrictions: {country:'aus'}
        };
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to include the parenthesis:

```
$scope.autocompleteOptions = {
types: ['(regions)'],
componentRestrictions: {country:'aus'}
};
```

This is also true for `'(cities)'`

https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table3

Comment: Does this solve your issue? If it does, it would be great if you can accept the answer :)

Comment: What about filter by `postal_code`. How?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `getPlacePredictions()` method. Check if you are not using the `getQueryPredictions()` method instead, in that case, that's the issue.

source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service?hl=es-419#AutocompleteService.getPlacePredictions